# Creating reusable forms with partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I'm trying to figure out the best way to create reusable forms with MVC. The situation is that I have a few forms used for editing groups of data that are used on several places on the site so obviously I dont want to copy paste the same forms for each of these places. I'm trying to use partial views but I cannot make it work completely and maybe I'm on the wrong track here.

The case which shows my problem is that I have one view with three different tabs (all tabs are in the same view and using simple javascript). On each tab I have added a partial view for editing that specific data. I have created the partial views with controller and everything. Each partial view contains its own form with validation summary.

If my controller actions simply return a PartialView the result is that the partial view is rendered alone, without the parent view surrounding it. Am I doing something wrong here if I get that result?

Am I on the wrong track to do this? Is there some other solution I should be doing instead?

To be more specific about the questions I have:

1) Is there a common pattern/solution for implementing components which include a form?
2) Using the solution here with partial views, how can I render the result of the controller action inside the master view the way it was rendered before the post?

Parts of the code for the master view:

```
<div class="tab-content no-border padding-24">
    <div id="editProfile" class="tab-pane in active">
    @{
        Html.RenderAction("EditUserProfile", "UserData", new { userId = Model.Id });
    }
    </div>
    <div id="password" class="tab-pane">
    @{
        Html.RenderAction("EditPassword", "UserData", new { userId = Model.Id });
    }
    </div>
</div>
```

The partial view for editing password:

```
@model Project.Web.Models.Shared.EditPasswordViewModel

<div id="summary">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
</div>

<div class="row">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("EditPassword", "UserData", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "editpasswordform", @class = "form-horizontal site-validation" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(o => o.Id)
        @Html.PasswordFor(o => o.Password, new { @class = "col-xs-12 form-control", type = "password", id = "password-field" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.NewPassword, new { @class = "col-xs-12", type = "text", id = "new-password-field"})
        @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.RepeatNewPassword, new { @class = "col-xs-12", type = "password", id = "repeat-new-password-field"})

        <button type="submit" class="width-35 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary">
            <i class="icon-hdd"></i>
            Save
        </button>
    }
</div>
```

Finally the controller method to save the password and go back to the same view:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize()]
public PartialViewResult EditPassword(EditPasswordViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Get the user
            User user = GetUserById(model.Id);

            //Update the user
            UpdatePassword(user.Username, model.Password, model.NewPassword);
        }

        return PartialView("_EditPassword", model);
    }
    catch (DomainException ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
        return PartialView("_EditPassword", model);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you should provide some code snippet related to your problem

Comment: is your form using ajax.beginform or html.beginform?

Comment: Question here more bright and brief or at least place detailed problem to solve. regards.